# How to capture the kill -3 info in logback

Tags: java, profile, monitor, logback

We have two logs in project, one is standard output using: java project.jar > output.log; the other is logback configured in the logback.groovy.

And when I use kill -3 to capture the thread dump info, they went to the output.log. 
Any way to output these info to the logback ?

And if I add the param -verbose:gc, how to output to the logback as well?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot capture this information within the Java application.  In both cases, the output comes from the JVM native code libraries and doesn't go through the Java IO libraries.

Comment: Thanks， I also not find the ways. So i wrote a script to parse the output